# How can I remove the title bar / undecorate the window in FLTK on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, titlebar, fltk

I have been doing some things with FLTK on Linux lately, and now I've wondered how I can remove the title bar / undecorate the window. The target Operating System is Linux, but it would be preferrable if it runs on wayland as well as on xorg.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community This wouldn't be helpful as the problem isn't specific to my code, but rather to any FLTK project.

Comment: Have a look for FLTK splash screen on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There are two functions that can be used: `border(int b)` and `clear_border()`.

The `border(int b)` function tells to the window manager to show or not the border: see [here](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#a72f5733f13cb6d8b646f1e7ffcd92333) the documentation. This can be used during the execution.

The other useful function is `clear_border()`: calling it before the `Fl_Window::show()` function makes the window manager hide the border. See [here](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Window.html#ab1f6119abc21b6636a13651b89bef1da) the documentation.

The (simple) code below shows how to use these functions.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>


void borderHide(Fl_Widget* w, void* p){
    Fl_Double_Window* win = (Fl_Double_Window*) p;
    // When the input of border() is 0 it tells to the window manager to hide the border.
    win->border(0);
}

void borderShow(Fl_Widget* w, void* p){
    Fl_Double_Window* win = (Fl_Double_Window*) p;
    // When the input of border() is nonzero it tells to the window manager to show the border.
    win->border(1);
}

int main(){

    Fl_Double_Window* W = new Fl_Double_Window(200, 200,"Test");
    // Hide the border from the first execution.
    W->clear_border();

    // Button which implements the border() function for showing the border.
    Fl_Button* S = new Fl_Button(80,150,100,30,"Border on");
    S -> callback(borderShow,W);


    // Button which implements the border() function for hiding the border.
    Fl_Button* H = new Fl_Button(80,100,100,30,"Border off");
    H -> callback(borderHide,W);
    W->end();
    
    W->show();
   
    return  Fl::run();

}
```